# dramatist can't make \act and \DramPer work

Tags: errors, dramatist

I'm new to the use of both LaTeX and `dramatist`, so I suppose I'm doing some very crude error here.

I tried to get some example of `dramatist` code and copy paste, but I nevertheless have the problem. So here is my code, coming from another example on this website where I dumped some data from a Tchejov Play. My problem is that I don't have the expected result for `\act` and `\DramPer` (no act title, nor Dramatispersonae list appearing).

With this code, I get a blank document with only "author/title/date". If I put the `\DramPer` and `\act` lines as commentary (`%\DramPer`), I get my text.

What am I missing?

### LaTeX code

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% This is a simple template for a LaTeX document using the "article" class.
% See "book", "report", "letter" for other types of document.

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)

%%% Examples of Article customizations
% These packages are optional, depending whether you want the features they provide.
% See the LaTeX Companion or other references for full information.

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
% \usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
% \geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
% \geometry{margin=2in} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round
% \geometry{landscape} % set up the page for landscape
%   read geometry.pdf for detailed page layout information



%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{dramatist} 


%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS


%%% SECTION TITLE APPEARANCE


%%% ToC (table of contents) APPEARANCE


%%% END Article customizations

%%% The "real" document content comes below...

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
%\date{} % Activate to display a given date or no date (if empty),
         % otherwise the current date is printed 

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\Character[RANEVSKAÏA, LIOUBOV ANDREEVNA.]{Lioubov}{Liouba}
\Character[ANIA, sa fille.]{ANIA}{Ania}
\Character[ANIA, sa fille, dix-sept ans.]{ANIA}{Ania}
\Character[VARIA, sa fille adoptive, vingt-cinq ans.]{VARIA}{Varia}
\Character[GAEV, LEONID ANDREEVITCH, frère de Ranevskaïa.]{GAEV}{Gaev}
\Character[LOPARINE, IERMOLAÏ ALEXEEVITCH.]{LOPAKHINE}{Lop}
\Character[TROFIMOV, PIOTR SERGUEEVITCH, étudiant.]{TROFIMOV}{trof}
\Character[SIMEONOV PICHTCHIK, BORIS BORISSOVITCH, Propriétaire terrien.]{PICHTCHIK}{Pich}
\Character[CHARLOTTA IVANOVNA, Gouvernante.]{CHARLOTTA}{Char}
\Character[EPIRODOV, SEMIONE PANTELEEVITCH, Employé.]{EPIKHODOV}{Epi}
\Character[DOUNICHA, La bonne.]{DOUNIACHA}{Doun}
\Character[FIRS, Laquais, vieillard de quatre-ving-sept ans.]{FIRS}{Firs}
\Character[IACHA, Jeune laquais.]{IACHA}{Iacha}
\Character[Un passant.]{UN PASSANT}{Passant}
\Character[Le chef de gare.]{Le Chef de gare}{Lechefdegare}
\Character[Le receveur des postes.]{receveur}{Postes}
\Character[Des invités, des domestiques.]{invités}{invdom}


\DramPer



\act




\StageDirConf{\itshape\centering}{\par}

\StageDir{
    \begin{flushleft} Une chambre qu'on appelle toujours la chambre des enfants. L'une des portes donne sur la chambre d'Ania. Le point du jour, juste avant le lever du soleil. On est déjà en mai, les cerisiers sont en fleurs mais il fait froid, le brouillard du matin couvre la cerisaie. Les fenêtres de la chambre sont fermées.
    \end{flushleft}
}
\StageDir{
    \begin{flushleft}Entrent Douniacha, tenant une bougie à la main, et Lopakhine, un livre à la main.
    \end{flushleft}}

\begin{drama}

\Lopspeaks --But are you really well, father?
You look so pale.


\end{drama}


\end{document}
```

### Compilation results

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./sansnom-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 9 languages loaded.
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2015/03/05 v3.7c configurable book, report, article document class
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifetex/ifetex.sty
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/plain/ifetex/ifetex.tex))
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem11.clo)
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mempatch.sty))
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dramatist/dramatist.sty
(d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)

Package dramatist Warning: 

********************************************************
* No Configuration file found, using default settings. *
********************************************************
.

) (./sansnom-2.aux) [1{d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
] [2] [3] [4] [5] (./sansnom-2.aux) )<d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb><d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb><d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><d:/TE
XLIVE/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-dis
t/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on sansnom-2.pdf (5 pages, 69154 bytes).
SyncTeX written on sansnom-2.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on sansnom-2.log.
```

Comment: This compiles normally for me, using both `pdfLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`. Why are you using `pdfTeX` instead of `pdfLaTeX`?

Comment: @Fato39: The OP does not use `pdftex`, that's only the general backend for 'all' TeX executables. The format is clearly `pdflatex`, as can been seen from `preloaded fmt=pdflatex`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see, thank you for clarification. I'm afraid then I don't have any ideas as to why the example would not compile properly.

Comment: @Tchaf: Did you see page 3 and page 5?

Comment: There's only one page I think. I've just put the characters list and the first act/scene stage directions and one sentence of dialogue.

Comment: @Tchaf: The message
... [1{d:/TEXLIVE/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
] [2] [3] [4] [5] ...
in your Compilation results shows that the result is five pages.

Comment: Well done... When I put the /DramPer and /act, it changes the layout... with additionnal blank pages!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so @Akira Kakuto got it in one: the **\DramPer** and **\act** commands add a blank page whereas **\scene** or **\section** does not. I simply didn't notice... sorry all, and thanks for your answers.

The layout without these commands fit in just one page.